# How to select images whose src is set in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Select these:

```
<img src="...">
```

but not:

```
<img />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

```
$("img[src]")
```

Comment: cf doc: "[attribute] Matches elements that have the specified attribute."

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgFile = $("img").attr("src");
```

Comment: This selects the attribute `src` on `img` elements, not `img` elements that have an src attribute